# Storing a git commits to a text-file

Tags: git

How do I store a change set (or a commit) as a text file, so that I can load/apply those changes back into my current active branch?

i.e I am expecting something like this

```
git commit --to-file ~/temp_commit_1.txt
```

which will create a text file that contains the commit details that can be understood by git. Does such a mechanism exist or what is the closest way of achieving this behavior?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### `git format-patch`

You should use the `git format-patch`

```
git format-patch <master>
0001-commit-msg1.patch
0002-commit-msg2.patch
```

The above code will create each commit in its own file.

If you want to create **just one file**, to more easily use as an attachment or upload somewhere else, you can use the `--stdout` option and redirect the output to a file:

```
git format-patch master --stdout > output_file.patch

# EXample: The last 10 patches from head in a single patch file:
git format-patch -10 HEAD --stdout > 0001-last-10-commits.patch
```

#### To apply the patch:

```
git am <patch file>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what `@CodeWizard` said, if you talk about branches in *the same* repository, there's no sense in messing with textual patches in files as you can just use the [`git cherry-pick`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) command which does just that: takes a commit or a series of commits on a branch and applies them one-by-one to the currently checked out branch as textual patches.

---

On a side note, if you need to transfer a series of commits between not directly connected Git repositories, `git bundle` might be easier than commands working with patches: the former produces a self-contained "archive" from which you can fetch, pull cherry-pick and so on—just like from a regular Git repository.